# intl ICU version installed on your system is outdated (60.2)

Tags: php, symfony, xampp, icu

Hello symfony developers, I´m taking a symfony course. When I try "http://localhost/test/web/config.php" i got this error:

intl ICU version installed on your system is outdated (60.2) and does not match the ICU data bundled with Symfony (62.1)

To get the latest internationalization data upgrade the ICU system package and the intl PHP extension.

And I don't know what needs to remove this recommendation.

i'm using symfony 3.4.*, PHP 7.2.3 with XAMPP as server and Windows 10 as OS.